# httpadapter in Esper CEP implementation

Tags: http, xmlhttprequest, adapter, esper, complex-event-processing

I need to send data to a web page from esper engine using httpadapter. I followed the steps mentioned in examples. Somehow  it didn't wwork. I need to send using plain java object. Also let me know how to configure web server for the request and response.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sending from Web page to Web Server . Please check all your java/Event class variables are starting with small letters.

For Example  : if you declare CardId : will not work .. Give null
                                 carId  : will work.

Configure web server : HttpOutputAdapter

```
Its all matters in URI. your web server uri and service name you invoke.

 http://host:port/servicename?parameters.
```